# Simple self-extracting installer won't run a simple batch file

Tags: batch-file, iexpress

I'm having trouble creating my first self-extracting installer using IExpress.exe.

HelloWorld.bat:

```
echo Hello
pause
```

HelloWorld.SED:

```
[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
PackagePurpose=InstallApp
ShowInstallProgramWindow=0
HideExtractAnimation=0
UseLongFileName=1
InsideCompressed=0
CAB_FixedSize=0
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0
RebootMode=N
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt%
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense%
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage%
TargetName=%TargetName%
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName%
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched%
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd%
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd%
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd%
SourceFiles=SourceFiles
[Strings]
InstallPrompt=
DisplayLicense=
FinishMessage=
TargetName=C:\Users\lbarnes\Documents\InstallerTest\HelloWorld.EXE
FriendlyName=HelloWorld
AppLaunched=Hello.bat
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
UserQuietInstCmd=
FILE0="Hello.bat"
[SourceFiles]
SourceFiles0=C:\Users\lbarnes\Documents\InstallerTest\
[SourceFiles0]
%FILE0%=
```

But when I use IExpress.exe

```
IExpress.exe /N HelloWorld.SED
HelloWorld.EXE
```

I get a pop-up window with this message

> Error creating process Command /c C:\Users\lbarnes\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP000.TMP\Hello.bat
>
> Reason: The system cannot find the file specified.

That file is present as verified using

```
dir C:\Users\lbarnes\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP000.TMP\Hello.bat
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the AppLaunched value to `cmd.exe /c hello.bat`

Comment: Squashman already answered you. The reason is that IExpress was created in the the times when the default command processor was `command.com` (which is no more available in 64 bit machines) and tries to launch a bat file using it. So you need to force cmd.exe usaga with thr `AppLaunched` directive.

Comment: I did not specify "Command". IExpress did that. Is there a better utility than IExpress?

BTW, it seems to have worked when I changed from a .bat file to a .cmd file. Maybe that enticed IExpress to use cmd.exe.

Comment: @Squashman
The IExpress tool doesn't generate proper working Executable if the Batch script inherently fires up UAC for Administrator access and then continues the rest of the processing... Any idea, how can I change/tweak the .sed file to generate reliable and working executables of Self-Elevating Batch scripts / utilities ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: IExpress Wizard]

Add **cmd /c hello.bat** in the Install Program dropdown.
It automatically pick only the batch file, you need to change the AppLaunched parameter as the above.